# How do I compress photos for my jekyll website?

Tags: jekyll

I'm a very junior developer and just made my first [Jekyll/GitHub Pages website](https://alkidel.github.io/lunchwithlucy/).

I would like to compress the photos to make the webpage load faster.

I've read about gems such as `jekyll-compress-images` and `image_optim` but I'm not sure I'm installing and applying them correctly.

Am I going in the right direction? Is there any Jekyll plugin that I missed?

Answer (score 2):

Hi @alkidel and welcome.

`jekyll-compress-images` and `image_optim` seem to compress pictures: the images might be lighter afterwards, but you could get better results by also resizing them. From what I can see, the pixel dimensions of the images your website is serving are way too large.

I think [`jekyll-assets`](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-assets) is what you're looking for.